# can't find the dependence jar in m2e but in http://search.maven.org can?

Tags: java, maven

I can search the result for my open source jar: with jar id: server-test-toolkit

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.googlecode.server-test-toolkit%22

but why in m2e (maven in eclipse) I can't find the one:

[image]

ps:
1 I have one pom.xml only
2 I use the dependence info, it can download it, but can't search it in the tab.
So is it the m2e bug or any other issue?

Comment: The artifact search in m2e is done by downloading the index from remote repository.  Maybe m2e hasn't got the new index after its previous download, or the index in remote repo is not updated yet.

Comment: Are you inside a company using a repository manager?

Comment: how to get the new index? yes, I am in company.

Comment: You are in a company, but are you connected directly to the internet to get your maven artifacts, or are you using a repository manager to proxy the "world's" repositories? Eclipse is using its built in maven when installed as default. It has a settings.xml that might not be set correctly.

Comment: I don't change any config in setting.xml.

Answer (score 0):

1 Delete the cache from .m2/repository/.cache/m2e.  .m2\repository.cache\m2e\0.12.1\d9d714e11cb097b3ffcec91cccc65d3e\nexus-maven-repository-index.gz
2 Open your eclipse
3 Menu Windows > Preferences > Maven > User Settings > Update Settings
Eclipse will download it again, should work now.

the root cause is the index for maven repo has be cached and not to updated. So update it.